# How to locate the elements of developer tools page in chrome using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to locate the elements of developer tools page in chrome using selenium Web Driver. So i need the coding part of developer tools page to locate the particular elements in that page. How and where can i get the codes of developer tools page. Please help me out from this problem...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consult this page to know how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you meaning the html source? Your question is not very clear. Everything in the elements tab of the developers tools is gettable through "findElement" using selenium. Find the element you want to get and use selenium to pull it out. Simple.

Comment: from my experience, selenium not support that, the dev tool page not belong to 'browser'.  Seems chrome dev tool implement by javascript, you can search something from chromium developer site to see is possible to use driver.executeScript() to call chromium javascript api

Answer (score 0):

For chrome you have to xpath checker and for firefox(version below 53) you can use Firebug and Firepath

- For xpath checker:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-xpath-checker/aoinfihhckpkkcpholfhmkeplbhddipe?hl=en

- For Firebug

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: @faizal you can use firbug and xpath checker